# How to remap or revert a point into its former coordinate system after warpAffine has transformed it?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, rotation

I'm using *Template Matching* (TM) to find the location of all the **M**'s in the image (first image to the left) but I'm having trouble remapping the location of the matched point (which refers to a location inside a rotated ROI) back to the original image:

[image]

The problem is that I need to reverse (undo) a **warpAffine** transformation on this point and my computation is not perfect, as you can see on the right-most image above with the orange boxes.

I already looked into all the posts in SO related to this topic but none really helped since the operation I'm trying to reverse is slightly more complicated:

- [Center of rotated cv::Rect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19786333/176769)
- [How can I remap a point after an image rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30327659/176769)

In simple words, what does this application do?

1. It starts by loading images: the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA2Il.png) and the [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ybpf.png);
2. It creates 8 ROIs with their required rotation angles. The rotation angle is used later to correct the orientation of the M so that it stays horizontal and "*looks pretty*" for TM;
3. A loop iterates on every ROI in the list: selects a ROI, rotates it using `rotate_bound()` and then performs TM on it.;
4. When a TM operation is successful and finds the letter, it then tries to remap the point that defines the location of the match **from** a rotated ROI **to** coordinates in the original ROI, which then can be used to specify the correct location of the match inside the original image.

The main issue seems to be undoing all the operations that are defined in the rotation matrix that is created by `rotate_bound()`. By the way, if you never heard of this function, here is a [good reference](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/).

**How can I fix the remap computation?**

Here is a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# rotate_bound: helper function that rotates the image adds some padding to avoid cutting off parts of it
# reference: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/
def rotate_bound(image, angle):
    # grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w // 2, h // 2)

    # grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

    # compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int(np.multiply(h, sin) + np.multiply(w, cos))
    nH = int(np.multiply(h, cos) + np.multiply(w, sin))

    # adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

    # perform rotation and return the image (white background) along with the Rotation Matrix
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH), borderValue=(255,255,255)), M


# Step 1 - Load images
input_img = cv2.imread("target.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
template_img = cv2.imread("template.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
matches_dbg_img = cv2.cvtColor(input_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) # for debugging purposes

# Step 2 - Generate some ROIs
# each ROI contains the x,y,w,h and angle (degree) to rotate the box and make its M appear horizontal
roi_w = 26
roi_h = 26

roi_list = []
roi_list.append((112, 7, roi_w, roi_h, 0))
roi_list.append((192, 36, roi_w, roi_h, -45))
roi_list.append((227, 104, roi_w, roi_h, -90))
roi_list.append((195, 183, roi_w, roi_h, -135))
roi_list.append((118, 216, roi_w, roi_h, -180))
roi_list.append((49, 196, roi_w, roi_h, -225))
roi_list.append((10, 114, roi_w, roi_h, -270))
roi_list.append((36, 41, roi_w, roi_h, -315))

# debug: draw green ROIs
rois_dbg_img = cv2.cvtColor(input_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
for roi in roi_list:
    x, y, w, h, angle = roi
    x2 = x + w
    y2 = y + h
    cv2.rectangle(rois_dbg_img, (x, y), (x2, y2), (0,255,0), 2)

cv2.imwrite('target_rois.png', rois_dbg_img)
cv2.imshow('ROIs', rois_dbg_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow('ROIs')


# Step 3 - Select a ROI, crop and rotate it, then perform Template Matching
for i, roi in enumerate(roi_list):
    x, y, w, h, angle = roi
    roi_cropped = input_img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_rotated, M = rotate_bound(roi_cropped, angle)

    # debug: display each rotated ROI
    #cv2.imshow('ROIs-cropped-rotated', roi_rotated)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)

    # debug: dump roi to the disk (before/after rotation)
    filename = 'target_roi' + str(i)
    cv2.imwrite(filename + '.png', roi_cropped)
    cv2.imwrite(filename + '_rotated.png', roi_rotated)

    # perform template matching
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(roi_rotated, template_img, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    (_, score, _, (pos_x, pos_y)) = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    print('TM score=', score)

    # Step 4 - When a TM is found, revert the rotation of matched point so that it represents a location in the original image
    # Note: pos_x and pos_y define the location of the matched template in a rotated ROI
    threshold = 0.75
    if (score >= threshold):

        # debug in cropped image
        print('find_k_symbol: FOUND pos_x=', pos_x, 'pos_y=', pos_y, 'w=', template_img.shape[1], 'h=', template_img.shape[0])
        rot_output_roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi_rotated, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        cv2.rectangle(rot_output_roi, (pos_x, pos_y), (pos_x + template_img.shape[1], pos_y + template_img.shape[0]), (0, 165, 255), 2) # orange
        cv2.imshow('rot-matched-template', rot_output_roi)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyWindow('rot-matched-template')

        ###
        # How to convert the location of the matched template (pos_x, pos_y) to points in roi_cropped?
        # (which is the ROI before rotation)
        ###

        # extract variables from the rotation matrix
        M_x = M[0][2]
        M_y = M[1][2]
        #print('M_x=', M_x, '\tM_y=', M_y)
        M_cosx = M[0][0]
        M_msinx = M[0][1]
        #print('M_cosx=', M_cosx, '\tM_msinx=', M_msinx)
        M_siny = M[1][0]
        M_cosy = M[1][1]
        #print('M_siny=', M_siny, '\tM_cosy=', M_cosy)

        # undo translation:
        dst1_x = pos_x - M_x
        dst1_y = pos_y - M_y

        # undo rotation:
        # after this operation, (new_pos_x, new_pos_y) should already be a valid point in the original ROI
        new_pos_x =  M_cosx * dst1_x - M_msinx * dst1_y
        new_pos_y = -M_siny * dst1_x + M_cosy  * dst1_y

        # debug: create the bounding rect of the detected symbol in the original input image
        detected_x = x + int(new_pos_x)
        detected_y = y + int(new_pos_y)
        detected_w = template_img.shape[1]
        detected_h = template_img.shape[0]
        detected_rect = (detected_x, detected_y, detected_w, detected_h)

        print('find_k_symbol: detected_x=', detected_x, 'detected_y=', detected_y, 'detected_w=', detected_w, 'detected_h=', detected_h)
        print()

        cv2.rectangle(matches_dbg_img, (detected_x, detected_y), (detected_x + detected_w, detected_y + detected_h), (0, 165, 255), 2) # orange
        cv2.imwrite('target_matches.png', matches_dbg_img)
        cv2.imshow('matches', matches_dbg_img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Once again, here are the images that are required to run the application: [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA2Il.png) and [template image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ybpf.png).

Comment: homography transformation inversiob is just a matrix inversion. add a 0,0,1 row if necessary to invert

Comment: @Micka I got no luck doing that but a working example from you would be incredibly valuable on this question.

Comment: unfortunately I dont have time at the moment.

Comment: The more I look at this image, the more convinced I am that all that's missing is to rotate the orange box too. Their starting positions seems to be right on the money. OpenCV for Python is not very friendly for drawing rotated rectangles, though.

Comment: Turn the bounding box into a polyline/contours (a list of coordinates of the corners). You know the angle, and the top-left corner seems to be correctly located. So transform all the points -- rotation by the angle, with origin in top-left corner. Then draw a closed polyline.

Comment: Here's a quick draft: https://pastebin.com/uccHAB4P | Probably should round the coordinates properly instead of just cutting of the decimal places.

Comment: @DanMašek That's what I ended up doing but your solution is a little bit more elegant. Please add it as an answer! Add a note at the beginning to clarify that the problem was just a missing rotation in the rectangle before it was draw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there -- all that's missing is rotating the bounding box rectangle around its top-left corner by the known angle, and then drawing this rotated rectangle.

Since [`cv2.rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga07d2f74cadcf8e305e810ce8eed13bc9) only draws up-right rectangles, we need some alternative. One option is to represent the rectangle as a list of its corner points (for consistency, let's say, in clockwise order, starting from top-left). We can then draw it as a closed polyline going through those 4 points, using [`cv2.polylines`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaa3c25f9fb764b6bef791bf034f6e26f5).

---

To rotate the rectangle, we need to apply a geometric transformation on all its corner points. To do so, we first obtain a transformation matrix using [`cv2.getRotationMatrix2D`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gafbbc470ce83812914a70abfb604f4326).

We convert the corner points into homogenous coordinates, and calculate a dot-product of the transformation matrix with transposed array of coordinates.

For convenience (to have each point on single row) we transpose the result.

```
# Rotate rectangle defined by (x,y,w,h) around its top left corner (x,y) by given angle
def rotate_rectangle(x, y, w, h, angle):
    # Generate homogenous coordinates of the corners
    # Start top left, go clockwise
    corners = np.array([
        (x, y, 1)
        , (x + w, y, 1)
        , (x + w, y + h, 1)
        , (x, y + h, 1)
    ], np.int32)
    # Create rotation matrix to transform the coordinates
    m_rot = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((x, y), angle, 1.0)
    # Apply transformation
    rotated_points = np.dot(m_rot, corners.T).T
    return rotated_points
```

---

Now, instead of the call to `cv2.rectangle`, we first determine the corners of the rotated bounding box:

```
rot_points = rotate_rectangle(detected_x, detected_y, detected_w, detected_h, angle)
```

Since `cv2.polylines` requires integer coordinates, we [round](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html) the values and [convert the datatype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) of the array:

```
rot_points = np.round(rot_points).astype(np.int32)
```

And finally draw a closed polyline through the 4 corner points:

```
cv2.polylines(matches_dbg_img, [rot_points], True, (0, 165, 255), 2)
```

---

[image: Result image]